# How do I use Python to do the mouse hover action in selenium using javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, mouseevent, mousehover

How can I go to an element and perform mouse hover action using only javascript and Python?
for instance This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('il[class="reactions"]')

for btn in btns:
    **(I Want to Hover all 'btn' Element Using only "driver.execute_script" Method)**
    time.sleep(5)
    btn.click()
click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform mouse hover with Selenium you should use `ActionChains` library.
Also you should use Expected Conditions explicit wait to load all `btns` the elements.
With it your code will be as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'il[class="reactions"]')))
time.sleep(1)
btns = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('il[class="reactions"]')

for btn in btns:
    actions.move_to_element(btn).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    btn.click()
```

Comment: This is Not Working for Me, for an infinity Loop on the same page the mouse hover keeps hovering on the past element, I needed a javascript executor for this.